# Generic implementation of oracle.sql.ARRAY and oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am attempting to abstract out some implementation details from my persistence tier.  As it stands I have two functions one that creates an `ARRAY` and one that creates an `ArrayDescriptor`.  I am currently writing tests utilizing HSQL and keep running into an issue wherein I get a `ClassCastException` when converting from `JDBCConnection` to `OracleConnection`.  This is caused by the following:  [createDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ArrayDescriptor.html#createDescriptor_java_lang_String__java_sql_Connection_).  Is there a way to remove the Oracle details and use the concept of ARRAY and ArrayDescriptor in a generalized fashion?   I am currently not near my source code, so I will recall from memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JDBC 4 / Java 6 or later, you could try using the JDBC array creation method,

[Connection.createArrayOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

From memory, the Oracle specific APIs give you more options and flexibility, but using the JDBC APIs is really the only option if you want to use something else other than Oracle as your database.

---

Edit: According to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraarr.htm), Oracle JDBC drivers do not support createArrayOf().  So the best you could probably do is do an `instanceof` check in your code, use the Oracle specific APIs if you detect an OracleConnection and otherwise use Connection.createArrayOf().

Comment: Interesting, so I cannot fully abstract my way out of this.